# Running ASP.NET Boilerplate template under virtual directory

Tags: javascript, iis, aspnetboilerplate, virtual-directory, base-url

I have an Angular template created by ASP.NET Boilerplate. I have published it successfully and it is running smoothly on IIS under a website. My client, however, wants to have it run under a Virtual Directory rather than a website for itself.
[image]

I have updated the **appconfig.json** as below:

```
{
  "remoteServiceBaseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/Training",
  "appBaseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/Training"
}
```

and did the same with `App` in the **appSettings.json**:

```
"App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:8080/Training/",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:8080/Training/",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:8080/Training"
}
```

For some reason, when I run the app, I get the following errors that it cannot load some CSS and JavaScript bundles:
[image]

I have manually changed the **index.html** in the **wwwroot** folder and added `http://localhost:8080/Training/` to the beginning of each href. By doing that, all those errors have gone and now I am left with this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/appconfig.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Which I think is related to the **AppPreBootstrap.ts** file, where it reads from the **appconfig.json** file.

Do I have to make any changes in the application settings somewhere, before publishing it, to get rid of the above issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that `appRootUrl` ends with `'/'` in **AppPreBootstrap.ts**:

```js
private static getApplicationConfig(appRootUrl: string, callback: () => void) {
    appRootUrl += appRootUrl.endsWith('/') ? '' : '/'; // Add this line
    return abp.ajax({
        url: appRootUrl + 'assets/' + environment.appConfig,
        // ...
    }).done(result => {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems your template is v3.x. Copy the changes from commit [f20895b](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/f20895bd6af5003b996fabe70dc7ef15d54e8868?w=1) and then add the line mentioned in this answer.